# Unable to download EMDK for windows mobile 5.0 application

Tags: c#, .net, symbols, motorola, windows-mobile-5.0

I am a newbie in this field and I want to create a Windows Mobile application for my Motorola MC70 device.

My problem is that I am trying to download EMDK but I can't find it on internet.

I found various links on Google:-

http://support.symbol.com/

https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN

but all in vain.....

Can anyone give me the exact link to download EMDK for Windows Mobile???

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the handheld's Smybol/Motorola/Zebra SDK (currently named EMDK) at 'current' the owner site of the device's brand (as of this writing this is Zebra). Follow the current site's navigation and look for support or download and then the device model. You will then probably find the 'SDK'.

Reminder: internet and sites will always change and so any provided link may no longer work. Then use the site's navigation or contact support.

[Links deleted as no longer valid, no new links as these may change at any time]

Comment: None of these links work.

Comment: This "lazy guy" right here *did* that search at Zebra's. Until yesterday, no results were found searching for the term EMDK. Not sure why it now works all of a sudden. In any case, I still think you should edit your answer because it is misleading. I can't find anything information about EMDK being renamed to EMDT or EMCT.

Comment: Done. Links may be provided as of being valid at the time the question was answered. If the links will no longer work at some time, the answer was valid as of the time the answer was posted.

Comment: If this is about the downvote, please remember that SO's rating system isn't about "being right at some point in time", it's about usefulness. Link-only answers - although in this case it *was* the answer - are discouraged because they *are* likely to become useless over time (hence the downvote). You being "right" when you wrote this doesn't make it any more useful for the current reader. It's not the same as outdated answers about some development tool because there might still be people out there using a legacy version, making the answer useful for them. **TL/DR: downvote != punishment**

Comment: The question was about getting a link and that was provided at the time being asked. But I understand the point and now: what should we do with someone asking for a link which is for a big download?

Comment: As per SO's guidelines: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow (...)*. So ultimately the right thing to do would be voting to close the question altogether. If however you do want to answer then by all means go for it and collect the easy upvotes :) If you're lucky enough the provided link(s) will remain active for many, many years and be helpful for a lot of people. If not then track downvotes and comments and edit your answer accordingly. Or, if downvotes goes down below zero, delete it.

Comment: OK, I will remind that in future. Thanks for pointing this out.